# Remove PDF margins while using PDFFitPage in GhostScript

Tags: pdf, crop, ghostscript

I'm fitting a file with no margins (produced using a `pdfcrop` from a normal PDF file) to a given paper size using GhostScript:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dFIXEDMEDIA \
   -dPDFFitPage -d -dBATCH -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=864 \
   -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=612 -sOutputFile=$INPUT $OUTPUT
```

but the output has additional margins (I was cropping in order to get rid of them).

Is it possible to force GhostScript to produce output without these margins?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your file I cannot be certain, however I suspect that all you have done is set a /CropBox in the PDF file. By default Ghostscript uses the /MediaBox which is probably unchanged.

Try setting -dUseCropBox

Comment: Unfortunately - it doesn't work. Moreover, grep was unable to find CropBox inside the cropped file (while there was a MediaBox inside).

Comment: Well, I'd need to see the file to comment further I'm afraid. Can you at least give the MediaBox dimensions ?

Comment: -dUseCropBox removed the margin like charm in my pdf, thanks!